# OpenGL: Adding texture to square changes it to a triangle?

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl

I am following along with an exercise in O'Reilly's iOS Game Development Cookbook to draw a square with OpenGL using textures. This follows a previous recipe for creating a square without texture, and that worked fine. However, when I run the code with texture, as below, I see a triangle rather than a square. Also the triangle is not the shape I would expect if only one of the two triangles I am using to draw the square were drawn. Those are right triangles, whereas the triangle that is actually appearing is isosceles.

```
//Modified with addition of textureCoordinates
typedef struct {
    GLKVector3 position;
    GLKVector2 textureCoordinates;
} Vertex;

//Modified with addition of second set of braces{} per line
const Vertex SquareVertices[] = {
    {{-1, -1, 0}, {0,0}},
    {{1, -1, 0}, {1,0}},
    {{1, 1, 0}, {1, 1}},
    {{-1, 1, 0}, {0, 1}},
};


const GLubyte SquareTriangles[] = {
    0, 1, 2,
    2, 3, 0
};


@interface ViewController ()
{
GLuint _vertexBuffer;
GLuint _indexBuffer;
GLKBaseEffect *_squareEffect;
}
@end


@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    GLKView *view = (GLKView *)self.view;
    view.context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];

    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:view.context];

    //Create the vertex array buffer in which opengl will store vertices
    //tell opengl to give us a buffer
    glGenBuffers(1, &_vertexBuffer);

    //make this buffer be the active array buffer
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBuffer);

    //put this data into acive array buffer
    //it's as big as square vertices array so we can use the data from that array
    //also this data isn't going to change
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(SquareVertices), SquareVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    //now do same for index buffer, which shows which vertices to use to draw triangle
    glGenBuffers(1, &_indexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _indexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(SquareTriangles), SquareTriangles, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    //prepare gl effect
    _squareEffect = [[GLKBaseEffect alloc] init];

     _squareEffect.texture2d0.name = texture.name;

    //first set up projection matrix
    float aspectRatio = self.view.bounds.size.width/self.view.bounds.size.height;

    float fieldOfViewDegrees = 60.0;
    GLKMatrix4 projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakePerspective(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(fieldOfViewDegrees), aspectRatio, 0.1, 10.0);
    _squareEffect.transform.projectionMatrix = projectionMatrix;

    //next we describe how the square should be positions (6 units from camera)
    GLKMatrix4 modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeTranslation(0.0f, 0.0f, -6.0f);
    _squareEffect.transform.modelviewMatrix = modelViewMatrix;

    //CODE ADDED TO ADD TEXTURE
    NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"3px-tile" ofType:@"png"];
    GLKTextureInfo *texture = [GLKTextureLoader textureWithContentsOfFile:imagePath options:nil error:&error];
}


- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect{
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    //tell the effect it should prepare opengl to draw using configured settings
    [_squareEffect prepareToDraw];        

    //opengl alreayd knows the vertex array contains vertex data. we now tell how to use
    //tell opengl how the data is laid out for position of each vertex in vertex array
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);        

    //how that open gl knows where to find vertex positions, can draw them
    int numberOfVertices = sizeof(SquareTriangles)/sizeof(SquareTriangles[0]);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, numberOfVertices, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void *)offsetof(Vertex, textureCoordinates));
}

@end
```

Here's what I see:

[image: triangle]

Here's what I've tried:

- Back tracing to original square code - it still works if I change the code back
- Changing the location in the code where I add the texture - doesn't change anything, the triangle remains.

Why do I have a triangle and how can I get the square back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first call of `glVertexAttribPointer`

```
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
```

Has a stride of 0. This is may be incorrect, be safe and change it to `sizeof(Vertex)` (as it is in the second call).

> If stride is 0, the generic vertex attributes are understood to be tightly packed in the array. The initial value is 0.

Your second call of `glVertexAttribPointer` should be moved in front of your `glDrawElements`, although this is most likely not a problem right now.

I'm not sure if this solves the problem, but I can't comment yet so I have to submit an answer. Please update the code if you've fixed it.

Comment: Those two changes did it. Thanks a lot.